# Difference between 課 and 軌

Tags: translation, difference, cantonese

I would like to learn the equivalent translation for `course` in Cantonese, as in "I am taking a *course* online". For this reason I entered this word in the dictionary [CC-Canto](https://cantonese.org) and received both `課` and `軌` as results. What is the difference in meaning between these symbols and which is more accurate in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of the polysemy of the word 'course' in English. `課` and `軌` are fairly distinct characters in Cantonese.

- If you intend 'course' to mean **'A series of lectures or lessons in a particular subject, leading to an examination or qualification.'**, you use `課` (see a.), NEVER `軌`. Sometimes, even if you use 'course' directly in Cantonese, it's understandable (see b.).

  > a. 我將會上網**課**。I will attend online *lessons*.

  > b. 我嚟緊有個網上嘅**course**。I have an online *course* soon.
- If you intend 'course' to mean **'The way in which something progresses or develops.'**, you *may* use `軌`, but not always. This to me is not an accurate translation, because `軌` means more like 'track; trajectory; locus'.

  > 二戰嘅**始末/過程** the *course* of WWII
  > 鐵路**軌道** rail *track*

Comment: Duōxiè L Parker

Answer (score 1):

Even in some cases regarding education, you can still use 軌.

1. course = 課
2. curriculum = 軌 (approximately); the publication record, dozens of papers = 軌 (approximately)

For point 2, there are many courses in the curriculum to develop certain skills. "curriculum" is usually translated to 課**程**, where 程 has the meaning of journey or track.

Nowadays, China's universities introduce the "tenure track" to evaluate the academic performance of new teachers within their first 6-8 years. "tenure track" are translated to 常任軌.

However, I think 軌 is a more Western usage in education.